# SimpleLogic SPGridView example used in User Control

Tags: spgridview

I am trying to create the example at this link http://kitmenke.com/blog/2010/02/18/editing-in-sharepoints-spgridview/comment-page-1/#comment-1777 inside a User Control and not in a Web Part.

Here is my code-behind file named SimpleLogic.ascx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;


namespace SimpleLogic.ControlTemplates.SimpleLogic
{
    public partial class SimpleLogic : UserControl
    {
        const string LIST_NAME = "clientmatter";
        string[] LIST_COLUMNS = null;
        string VIEW_FIELDS = string.Empty;
        string[] DATA_KEY_NAMES = null;
        private SPSite site = new SPSite("http://abcdev");
        private SPWeb _currentweb;
        private SPWeb sPWeb;

        public SimpleLogic(SPWeb currentWeb)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.sPWeb = currentWeb;

            DATA_KEY_NAMES = new string[1];
            DATA_KEY_NAMES[0] = "ID";
            LIST_COLUMNS = new string[4];
            LIST_COLUMNS[0] = "ID";
            LIST_COLUMNS[1] = "Title";
            LIST_COLUMNS[2] = "clientid";
            LIST_COLUMNS[3] = "Client";
            VIEW_FIELDS = GetViewFields(LIST_COLUMNS);
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            base.CreateChildControls();
            SimpleLogic logic = new SimpleLogic(SPControl.GetContextWeb(Context));
            SimpleSPGrid grid = new SimpleSPGrid(logic);

            this.Controls.Add(grid);
        }

        public string[] GetDataKeyNames()
        {
            return DATA_KEY_NAMES;
        }

        public List<BoundField> GetColumns()
        {
            List<BoundField> fields = new List<BoundField>();
            fields.Add(GetBoundField("ID"));
            fields[0].ReadOnly = true;
            fields.Add(GetBoundField("Title"));
            fields.Add(GetBoundField("clientid"));
            fields.Add(GetBoundField("Client"));
            return fields;
        }

        private BoundField GetBoundField(string name)
        {
            BoundField bf = new BoundField();
            bf.HeaderText = name;
            bf.DataField = name;
            return bf;
        }

        public DataTable Select()
        {
            SPQuery q = new SPQuery();
            q.ViewFields = VIEW_FIELDS;
            q.Query = "<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='clientid' /></IsNotNull></Where>";
            SPList list = _currentweb.Lists[LIST_NAME];
            SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(q);
            return items.GetDataTable();
        }

        private string GetViewFields(string[] columns)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string field in columns)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("<FieldRef Name='{0}' />", field);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public void Update(Dictionary<string, string> data)
        {
            SPList list = _currentweb.Lists[LIST_NAME];
            int id = Int32.Parse(data["ID"]);
            SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(id);
            item["Title"] = data["Title"];
            item["clientid"] = data["clientid"];
            item["Client"] = data["Client"];
            item.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my extra class called "SimpleSPGrid.cs"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System.Collections;

namespace SimpleLogic.ControlTemplates.SimpleLogic
{
    class SimpleSPGrid
    {
        private SimpleLogic _logic;
        private ObjectDataSource _gridDS;
        private SPGridView _grid;

        public SimpleSPGrid(SimpleLogic logic)
        {
            _logic = logic;
        }

        protected sealed override void CreateChildControls()
        {

            const string GRIDID = "grid";
            const string DATASOURCEID = "gridDS";

            _gridDS = new ObjectDataSource();
            _gridDS.ID = DATASOURCEID;
            _gridDS.TypeName = typeof(SimpleLogic).AssemblyQualifiedName;
            _gridDS.ObjectCreating += new ObjectDataSourceObjectEventHandler(gridDS_ObjectCreating);
            _gridDS.SelectMethod = "Select";
            _gridDS.UpdateMethod = "Update";
            _gridDS.Updating += new ObjectDataSourceMethodEventHandler(gridDS_Updating);

            this.Controls.Add(_gridDS);

            _grid = new SPGridView();
            _grid.ID = GRIDID;
            _grid.DataSourceID = _gridDS.ID;
            _grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            _grid.DataKeyNames = _logic.GetDataKeyNames();

            CommandField command = new CommandField();
            command.ShowEditButton = true;
            _grid.Columns.Add(command);

            foreach (BoundField column in _logic.GetColumns())
            {
                _grid.Columns.Add(column);
            }
            this.Controls.Add(_grid);
        }

        void gridDS_Updating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in e.InputParameters)
            {
                string value = entry.Value == null ? null : entry.Value.ToString();
                data.Add(entry.Key.ToString(), value);
            }

            e.InputParameters.Clear();
            e.InputParameters.Add("data", data);
        }

        private void gridDS_ObjectCreating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceDisposingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.ObjectInstance = _logic;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting compile errors. Right now it states that

> “SimpleLogic.ControlTemplates.SimipleLogic.SimpleSPGrid.CreateChildControls():
>   no suitable method found to override”.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your class SimpleSPGrid does not inherit from anything, so I presume it inherits from Object. CreateChildControls() is a method of the Control class. Since the Object class does not have a CreateChildControls() method, SimpleSPGrid can't override it.

Solution: Change the line

```
Class SimpleSPGrid
```

to

```
Class SimpleSPGrid : Control
```

Another option, if you really want SimpleSPGrid to inherit from Object and not Control, change CreateChildControls to virtual, not override.